# HTML - Dragging and dropping - Move item back if not dropped on specific spot

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a little HTML game where you can drag and drop different items on to a predefined spot. It's for a game where you can create a burger with different ingredients. Now, I want a way of moving the different div's (you drag divs with an image on them) back when someone drags them. So they can't overlap and always come back to the same spot.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='dragdrop.js'></script>

    <title>Restaurant simulator</title>

    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/css/lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.2/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">


        <style>
            body {
                background: #fff;
                font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }

            #draggable,
            #draggable2,
            #draggable3 {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                padding: 0.5em;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
                background: white;
                border: 2px solid green;
                background-size: contain;
            }

            #droppable {
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                padding: 0.5em;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px;
            }

            .dropped {
                background: white;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#draggable").draggable();
                $("#draggable2").draggable();
                $("#draggable3").draggable();
                $("#droppable").droppable({
                    drop: function(event, ui) {
                        $(this)
                            .addClass("dropped")
                            .find("p")
                            .html("Dropped!");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>



        <div class="demo">

            <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-image: url('/images/food/Sla.png')">
                <!--         <p>Drag me to my target</p> -->
            </div>

            <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-image: url('/images/food/Meat.png')"></div>

            <div id="draggable3" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-image: url('/images/food/Sla.png')"></div>

            <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
                <p>Drop here</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- End demo -->



        <div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
            <p>Enable any DOM element to be droppable, a target for draggable elements.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- End demo-description -->



    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. may have asked a question a little too early. I found my answer: I upgraded the code a little, it now detects the ID of the dropped item. Hope I helped somebody.

I now have this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='dragdrop.js'></script>
<script src='http://livejs.com/live.js'></script>

<title>Restaurant simulator</title>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/css/lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.2/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">


    <style>
        body {
            background: #fff;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .draggable {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            left: 0;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
            background: white;
            border: 2px solid green;
            background-size: contain;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        #droppable {
            position: absolute;
            left: 600px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .dropped {
            background: white;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

        var num = 0;
        var draggableId;

        $(function() {
            //Make items dragable
            $("#draggable").draggable();
            $("#draggable2").draggable();
            $("#draggable3").draggable();
            $("#draggable4").draggable();
            $("#droppable").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    //Change counter one higher, for test purposes
                    num = num + 1;
                    //Get ID of dropped item
        draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                    $(this)
                    //Change look of drop-spot(gonna remove this someday)
                        .addClass("dropped")
                    //Change name of drop-spot
                        .find("p")
                        .html("Dropped!<br>Count: " + draggableId);

                    //change position of dropped item
                        $("#" + draggableId).css({left: 0, top: 0});
                }
            });


        });
    </script>



    <div class="demo">

        <!--            Dingen die kunnen worden gedropt -->
        <div class='draggable'  id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-image: url('/images/food/Sla.png')">
            <!-- <p>Drag me to my target</p> -->
        </div>
        <div class='draggable' id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-image: url('/images/food/Meat.png')"></div>
        <div class='draggable'  id="draggable3" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-image: url('/images/food/Sla.png')"></div>
        <div class='draggable'  id="draggable4" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-image: url('/images/food/Sla.png')"></div>

        <!--            Plek waar je dingen op moet droppen -->
        <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End demo-description -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'revert' with draggable to revert the div position.

```
$(function() { $("#draggable").draggable({ revert : function(event, ui) { // on older version of jQuery use "draggable" // $(this).data("draggable") // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable" // $(this).data("ui-draggable") $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = { top : 0, left : 0 }; // return boolean return !event; // that evaluate like this: // return event !== false ? false : true; } }); $("#droppable").droppable(); });
```